# Accessing IBOutlet from another class

Tags: ios, class, swift, null, iboutlet

I am calling a class function from my `ViewController` class like this:

```
Buttons.set_cornerRadius(10)
```

I have another `.swift` file where I have the function declared:

```
class Buttons {

      class func set_cornerRadius(radius: CGFloat) {
          ViewController().someButton.layer.cornerRadius = radius
      }
}
```

When I'm trying to run this it throws the error: `"Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional Value"`.

I checked the *Storyboard-IBOutlet* connections already. Everything is connected right.
If I call the method in the same class like this, everything works:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var someButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        set_cornerRadius(10)
    }

    func set_cornerRadius(radius: CGFloat) {
        someButton.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    }
}
```

How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong/not understanding right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to access a real instance of `ViewController` and not some generic instantiation

Comment: Can you give me some example Code on how to do this?

Comment: Why not just set the corner radius in your ViewController?

Comment: This is just some example Code I provided. I do have a lot more Buttons to take care of. I just don't want all that text in the same .swift file as the other methods if this makes any sense :D

Comment: if all the buttons are on the same UIViewController, just make an extension of `ViewController` and that removes the need to have it in the same file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You access a generic `ViewController`, but need to use an existing `UIView`. Do something like this:

```
class Test: UIViewController {

    class func set_cornerRadius(yourView: UIView, radius: CGFloat) {
        yourView.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    }
}
```

That way, you pass the `UIView` you want to set the corner-radius.

Comment: I am going to try this! :)

Comment: It seems to work if I use class func set_cornerRadius(yourView:ViewController, radius CGFloat) { some code }         and call it with       set_cornerRadius(self, 10)

Answer (score 2):

You extend your ViewController class like so:

```
extension ViewController {
    func set_cornerRadius(radius: CGFloat) {
         someButton.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    }
}
```

Now you can call this method in your original `ViewController` file using: `set_cornerRadius(someValue)` in your `viewDidLoad` or wherever you want. You can put this extension in a different file.